Deprecated: attempt to access invalid property :_id Caller: CRM_Core_Form::getVar
Wordpress: 6.5.3
CiviCRM: 5.73.2
DB: MySql8
PHP: 8.1
When I fill in a registration on an event form and click review the following message appears on the screen:
Deprecated: attempt to access invalid property :_id Caller: CRM_Core_Form::getVar in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1132
Deprecated: attempt to access invalid property :_id Caller: CRM_Core_Form::getVar in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1132
Deprecated: attempt to access invalid property :_id Caller: CRM_Core_Form::getVar in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1132
Deprecated: attempt to access invalid property :_id Caller: CRM_Core_Form::getVar in /home/cremorne/www/www/prodwp/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1132
What is going on here?
How do I get rid of this message?
I assume there is something old in the code being executed ?
Help please?

Do you have any custom extensions?

Yes extensions enabled include: Action Provider, eWay Recurring Payment Processor, CiviCRM Export to Excel, AdminUI (Preview), CKEditor4, CKEditor5, Contribution cancel actions, Firewall, Form Protection, Custom search framework, CiviRules, Email API, The Island Theme
